# Meaning of 「以上」 when someone finishes his/her speech and says 「以上」

Tags: usage, meaning

What is the meaning of 「以{い}上{じょう}」 when someone finishes his/her speech and says 「以上」? For example - the lawyer at the court after his speech says 「以上」and stops speaking then.

Comment: I can't imagine just saying "以上" to end a speech. I am pretty sure you say the complete "以上です".

Comment: It was a drama リーガルハイ - on NHK/FujiTV - and the main character at the court did so..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The meaning is "that's all", in the sense of "(all that there is, I've said) before".

The [second definition of 以上 here](http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/leaf/jn2/11464/m0u/%E4%BB%A5%E4%B8%8A/) shows that "above" is equated with "before", and the fourth definition corresponds to the usage you're referring to.